# How to retain atime stamp when converting a Ruby hash to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have a Ruby hash that is an Active Record created using factory_bot:

```
@task_array = []
list.flatten(1).each do
  ... 
  task = Factorybot.create(taskList)
  print task.attributes
  @task_array << task.attributes
end
print @task_array
```

`print` prints the hash:

```
task = { 
  "id"=>1239,  
  "created_at"=>Sat, 04 Jan 2020 00:00:00 CST -06:00, 
  "updated_at"=>Wed, 08 Apr 2020 00:00:00 CST -06:00
}
```

but then when I write it to a JSON array like this:

```
 @task_array << task.attributes
```

it outputs like this:

```
{
  "id" : 1239,
  "created_at" : "01/04/2020",
  "updated_at" : " 04/08/2020"
}
```

What should I do to retain the timestamps when converting a Ruby hash to JSON?

Comment: This is not what happens for me. I suspect it has something to do with your JSON serializer. Search your codebase for `def to_json` and `def as_json` overrides, look into your serializer configuration. If all else fails, use a debugger to step into your call that converts to json, and keep stepping until you find where those times are getting cast.

Comment: The Hash class doesn't have an ``attributes`` method.  I think you are missing some details of what you are doing.

Comment: @AnaMaríaMartínezGómez - i updated the question

Comment: How is ``@task_array`` defined? Can you post the code of you serializer? As @Unixmonkey pointed out, this is not the default behaviour

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is missing essential information. We need the smallest piece of complete code that demonstrates the problem. JSON works very well, so the problem is in your code; It looks like you don't understand how Ruby serializes DateTime or Time objects when being printed, and/or how JSON serializes them. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: See https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Extended+rendering+and+loading+of+Ruby+objects. Reading the entire [JSON](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) documentation, and the [Psych](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/psych/rdoc/index.html) docs will help.

Comment: ``@task_array`` is just an array, not a JSON array. I do not see where the JSON conversion is being made. I think you still miss some details.